# Loading Google MAP Markers from my Database

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have followed the google api tutorial bit by bit trying to load up my database markers from an external database but to no success.

https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3

The map is loading but no markers are being shown I have used the following version for to pull my the markers

```
   <?php  
$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0");
$node = $dom->createElement("markers");
$parnode = $dom->appendChild($node); 

require_once ('classes/DB.php');
$db = new DB();
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM markers");

header("Content-type: text/xml"); 

// Iterate through the rows, adding XML nodes for each

while ($row = $db->fetchData($result)){  
  // ADD TO XML DOCUMENT NODE  
  $node = $dom->createElement("marker");  
  $newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);   
  $newnode->setAttribute("name",$row['name']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("address", $row['address']);  
  $newnode->setAttribute("lat", $row['lat']);  
  $newnode->setAttribute("lng", $row['lng']);  
  $newnode->setAttribute("type", $row['type']);
} 

echo $dom->saveXML();

?>
```

when i load this page I get the markers in source of the page but when then i load the page i still dont get to see the markers

```
    <!DOCTYPE html >
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>PHP/MySQL & Google Maps Example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    var customIcons = {
      restaurant: {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png'
      },
      bar: {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png'
      }
    };

    function load() {
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(47.6145, -122.3418),
        zoom: 13,
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
      });
      var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

      // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
      downloadUrl("pointer_1.php", function(data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
          var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
          var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
          var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
          var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
          var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
          var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: point,
            icon: icon.icon
          });
          bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
        }
      });
    }

    function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(html);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      });
    }

    function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
      var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
          new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
          new XMLHttpRequest;

      request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
          request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
          callback(request, request.status);
        }
      };

      request.open('GET', url, true);
      request.send(null);
    }

    function doNothing() {}
    //]]>
  </script>

  </head>

  <body oncreate="load()">
    <div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 300px"></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

xml out putted once source is seen

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<markers>
    <marker name="Pan Africa Market" 
            address="1521 1st Ave, Seattle, WA" lat="47.608940" 
            lng="-122.340141" 
            type="restaurant"/>
    <marker name="Buddha Thai &amp; Bar" 
            address="2222 2nd Ave, Seattle, WA" 
            lat="47.613590" lng="-122.344391" 
            type="bar"/>
    <marker name="The Melting Pot" 
            address="14 Mercer St, Seattle, WA" lat="47.624561" 
            lng="-122.356445" 
            type="restaurant"/>
    <marker name="Ipanema Grill" 
            address="1225 1st Ave, Seattle, WA" 
            lat="47.606365" lng="-122.337654" 
            type="restaurant"/>
    <marker name="Sake House" 
            address="2230 1st Ave, Seattle, 
            WA" lat="47.612823" 
            lng="-122.345673" 
            type="bar"/>
    <marker name="Crab Pot" 
            address="1301 Alaskan Way, Seattle, WA" 
            lat="47.605961" 
            lng="-122.340363" 
            type="restaurant"/>
    <marker name="Mama's Mexican Kitchen" 
            address="2234 2nd Ave, Seattle, WA" 
            lat="47.613976" 
            lng="-122.345467" 
            type="bar"/>
    <marker name="Wingdome" 
            address="1416 E Olive Way, Seattle, WA" 
            lat="47.617214" 
            lng="-122.326584" 
            type="bar"/>
    <marker name="Piroshky Piroshky" 
            address="1908 Pike pl, Seattle, WA" 
            lat="47.610126" 
            lng="-122.342834" 
            type="restaurant"/>
</markers>
```

Any idea what i might have done wrong?

Comment: How does the returned XML look like?

Comment: once run it returns a blank page but once i view the source

Comment: i have edited the post with the source being outputted

Comment: [Your XML works for me](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GenericMapBrowser.asp?filename=SO_markers_120140321.xml) (this page expects different attributes, but the lat/lng work)

Comment: Are you sure that you load the page that requests the pointer_1.php via `http://`  (when you load the page via file:// the php-file will also be requested via file:// , the PHP-code wouldn't be parsed)

Comment: @Dr.Molle, if the PHP is not being parsed, how can OP post the source being outputted?

Comment: He  said he got 2 results(source or blank page), the obvious reason for that is that he loads the file in two different ways: **1.** via `http://`(he will see the xml-source, the PHP has been parsed, that's how it should be) **2.** via `file://` (he will see a blank page because there is not output outside of the php-tags, the PHP hasn't been parsed). When he would take a look at browser->viewsource he would see the unparsed php-code in this case.

Comment: I'm opeining pointer_1 through a browser so through http alm but when this is done page is empty and in source there's the xml

Comment: Hey @Dr.Molle, you are propably right, so why not post a solution so we can upvote?

Comment: any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: on more testing i have managed to load the pointer if i change link downloadURL to an actual xml file with markers, so im guessing the problem is in the php

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot to assign the marker to a map, like so:

```
marker.setMap(map);
```